# PyCharm "Execute Selection in Python Console" Produces FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pycharm

I am very new to PyCharm and I'm trying to execute a very simple set of code using Execute Selection in Python Console:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('mapgroupproto.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for t in root.findall("."):
    print(t.attrib)
```

When I select the first 3 lines, and attempt to run them, I get:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mapgroupproto.xml'`

even though the file, mapgroupproto.xml, is in the same directory as the python file I'm running. Executing the code using *RUN* works perfectly fine, every time.

Comment: _"is in the same directory as the python file"_ isn't actually what matters. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, not the source file your write them in.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import os 
os.getcwd()
```

The above would return you the current working directory where the code is being executed. If it is not the same as where you kept the `.xml` file, then you'll always encounter the `FileNotFoundError` when using a relative path. You can either change your current working directory by:

```
os.chdir('/path/to/your/desired/directory') # Where you kept the `.py` script and the `.xml` file.
```

Or you can paste the full path here:

```
tree = ET.parse('/path/to/mapgroupproto.xml')
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm guessing this is a function of the IDE and not Python, itself, since the .py script picks up the file, perfectly fine.

Comment: No, this is not a function within the IDE. I guess when you are executing the `.py` script outside Pycharm, you are already running it from that directory, which is why you don't get the `FileNotFoundError`. You should be able to run the same script from the Pycharm terminal without modifying anything when you ensure that you are in that same directory.

Comment: Right. Poor choice of words. It's caused because neither the `xml` nor the `py` is not in the project's working folder, within the IDE. I just loaded them as individual files. Putting them in the root of the project folder solved the issue.